# Has anyone successfully implemented Azure AD auth using Server Side Rendering Angular (Angular Universal)?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, angular8, angular-universal, azure-ad-msal

Currently We have an app that is using Angular Universal for Rendering. We have MSAL auth installed but we get random infinite loops with auth, especially new users.

We have tried catching these events and handling them but it does not seem to work. Looked at some documentation that says, MSAL is still not supported with Node and Server Side Apps.

I cannot use AUTH0. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish the auth against azure ad in this type of app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) at the moment works only with single page applications. Support for Node applications is on the [roadmap](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki#roadmap).

Still, there are a number of [3rd party libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) that you can use for this. I would suggest using [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad). You can see a sample application [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-nodejs).